# Sets and Countablity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this set finite, countably infinite, or uncountable:

a) $V = \{f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\}$ (the set of all functions that map each natural number to a natural number.

b) $\mathbb{Z}^3=\{(a,b,c):a,b,c∈\mathbb{Z}\}$ (the set of triples of integers)

Can I just say that we can create a mapping for each triplet in the sense that $(0,0,0) \to 0$, $(1,0,0) \to 1$, $(1,0,1) \to 2$ etc... every triplet will be accounted for and only once (bijection). Therefore, it is countable?

c) $T = \{p(x) : p(x) = a_nx^n +\cdots + a_1x + a_0\mid n \in \mathbb{N},\; a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ (the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients, of any degree)

I believe you use induction on just a polynomial of degree 2 (whose countability proof is identical to the question above)...but am not exactly getting it

Help appreciated please.

Comment: Can you use that a countable union of countable sets is countable?

Comment: yes. i think so although could you give a little insight to that?

Comment: My first comment with prime numbers was a bit greedy, as @Matt has told me. You can just use the fact that $$\left|\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right| = |\mathbb N\times\mathbb N| = |\mathbb N|$$ where with regards to the last equality I've already replied in another comment to you. Here $A_n$ are any countable sets.

Comment: @Ilya, LiveYourLife: This of course cannot be proved by induction, and requires *more* assumptions in your theory. If you are taking a naive course in set theory and discrete mathematics then you should find out if you are allowed to use this assumption.

Answer (score 6):

In a) the cardinality of the set in question is $|\mathbb{N}|^{|\mathbb{N}|}$, do you see why? To see what this means regarding cardinality note that $|\mathbb{R}| = 2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$. That's uncountable so your set in question is, too.

In b) you have a product of three countable sets. You can argue that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is countable by finding a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$ and then by induction, $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is countable as well. So: yes, you're right.

**Edit**
 If $f$ denotes the function that enumerates $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$ then you can define an onto function $F: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n$ as follows:

$$ (i,j) \mapsto (f(i), g(j)) $$ where $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is defined as

$$ g(j) := \begin{cases} k + 1 & j = 2k \\ -k & j = 2k + 1
   \end{cases} $$

Note that this assumes that you showed that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable and that you know the theorem that says that if $X$ is a countable set and $h: X \to Y$ is surjective then $Y$ is countable.

c) <s>is the same as b) if you replace $3$ by $n + 1$.</s>  See Asaf's or Rasmus' answer.

**Edit 2**

I'll add Rasmus' answer in my own words, just for completion:

Note that you can think of the polynomial $p(x) = a_n x^n + \dots + a_0$ as a vector $(a_n , \dots , a_0) \in \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$. 
Then $T = \{ p(x) \mid p(x) = a_n x^n + \dots + a_0 , n \in \mathbb{N}, a_i \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{ \mathbb{Z}^n \} $

You showed in b) that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is countable so this is a countable union of countable sets and therefore countable, too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In c), $n$ is not fixed.

Comment: @Rasmus: Oh. You're right! Let me fix my answer...

Comment: @Rasmus: Ah, not necessary. You answered that quite well already. : )

Comment: thank you! this was very helpful. Although, I have one question: can you help me with the actual induction process?

Base case: Z x Z is countable
Inductive hyp: assume (Z)^(n - 1) is countable
Inductive step: Z^n is also countable because the multiplication of two countable sets is countable, the two sets being Z^(n-1) and Z... is this how to do it?

Comment: Base: if $X_1,X_2$ are countable then $X_1\times X_2$ is countable (you can verify it be building bijection from pairs of positive integers $(m,n)$ to the set $\mathbb N$, e.g. considering $2^m3^n$). Inductive step: if $X_1\times\dots X_{n-1}$ is countable, hence $(X_1\times\dots X_{n-1})\times X_n$ is countable .

Comment: @LiveYourLife: If you know that $\mathbb Z^n$ is countable, you can just write $\mathbb Z$ instead. You simply reduce it to the case of two sets.

Comment: @LiveYourLife: Sorry for the late reply. I added  my response to your comment into my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Matt's answer gives you a good idea for (a),

(b) Union of countable sets is countable, so is the product of two countable sets. Using induction we can show that *finite* union of countable sets is countable, and *finite* products are countable.

(c) However, to show that the polynomials over $\mathbb Z$ are countable you need either to use an assumption that *countably infinite* unions are countable, or a clever trick.

The clever trick is that a polynomial can be identified by its coefficients, which are a finite subset of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb N$. Finally, all finite subsets of countable sets give out a countable set.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

a) Read about [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

b) If your map is "take the sum of the three entries", then it is not injective because both $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are mapped to $1$. Can you find a proof in your notes saying that if $X$ and $Y$ are countable then the product set $X\times Y$ is countable?

c) Try to find a surjection from $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\ \mathbb Z^n$ onto the set $T$. Then prove that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\ \mathbb Z^n$ is countable as a union of countably many countable sets.

Comment: The fact that countable union of countable sets is countable requires some choice; however the fact that polynomials are countable does not need such assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Yet one more method:

a) Prove that if X is uncountable and f:X->Y is an injection then Y is uncountable (hint look at the contrapositive). There is a 'obvious' injection from the reals to N^N.

b) Once you show Z ~ N it's on;t neccesary to prove NxN ~ N; a standard way is to consider an injection from NxN to N from the use of primes. (hint: look at products of primes - pick exponents wisely). From an induction you then have the result (and equivalence of cardinilty).

c) This has been addressed by others well.